# 途中で or 時に? And what's the difference?

Tags: grammar

交差点を渡る**途中で/時に**ふと何かに当てられた

In this sentence, I wonder which one is correct or better than the other?
I also have trouble to understand what exactly 途中で is used for, since in almost any case I feel like I could use 時 as well.

Comment: First means "On the way", second means "when". So for me using the first it would mean: "All of sudden I was hit by something on my way crossing/While Crossing the intersection.". The second would be "All of the sudden something hit me when I was crossing the intersection." . As for them being interchangeable might be a matter of how you're wording your sentence, just like in english. But as i'm not so familiar with these word too, I'll let someone else oficially answer this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

時に is generic "when", whereas 途中で is "in the middle". They are often interchangeable but the latter would sound more emphatic. Compare 寝ている時に "when I was sleeping" vs 寝ている途中で "in the middle of sleeping".

They are not always interchangeable. Use "when" if you don't have to say "in the middle".

> - 私は勉強する時に眼鏡をかけます。 I wear glasses when I study.
> - [?] 私は勉強する途中で眼鏡をかけます。 [?] I wear glasses in the middle of studying.

Comment: Doesn't 途中で also has a "spatial" aspect that 時に lacks?  It seems it's possible to say 道の途中で, whereas 道の時に doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @kroki Yes, 途中 doesn't have to follow a verb, just as "in the middle of" doesn't have to be followed by a verb.